# How to extract a new list from an object field in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, how do I extract a new list from the following:

```
   def people = [ 
           new Person(name:"Tom", yearOfBirth:1985),
           new Person(name:"Abigail", yearOfBirth:1987),
           new Person(name:"Joyce", yearOfBirth:1984),
           new Person(name:"James", yearOfBirth:1987),
           new Person(name:"Scott", yearOfBirth:1985),
           new Person(name:"Ruth", yearOfBirth:1984)
       ]  

   class Person {
       String name
       int yearOfBirth
   }
```

so that the new list looks like this:

```
 ["Tom", "Abigail", "Joyce", "James", "Scott", "Ruth"]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do:

```
def names = people.name
```

Comment: Perfect, how would I replace "Tom" with "Tim" in the process?

Comment: You'd need something like `people.collect { it.name == 'Tom' ? 'Tim' : it.name }`

Comment: @tim_yates Is there any reason you prefer this instead of `def names = people*.name`? I personally prefer the later. (BTW, i find it funny that Reimeus wants to replace Tom with you =P)

Comment: @epidemian they both end up as the same thing assuming people is a list... looking through my code, I use both :-/ I like `*.` as it expresses what you're doing more, but `.` is less typing ;-) and it's a good thing we replaced Tom, he wasn't pulling his weight ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates Well, in this case i feel that both syntaxes would be fine, as it's a quite simple example. But in general i prefer the `*.prop` as i feel its meaning is more obvious; it _always_ means `.collect { it.prop }`. The `people.name` option relies on quite a bit of magic on the `people` object (a `propertyMissing` implementation, and it not having a `name` property) which i preferably don't want to remember every time i see that expression :)