# Groovy dot notation on lists

Tags: syntax, groovy

I am not understanding the purpose of the following construction in Groovy.

Whenever you have a collection of stuff, call it `items`, you can map over an attribute just by accessing that attribute on the collection, that is,

```
items.prop == items.collect { it.prop }
```

This looks weird to me, because I would think that the first notation actually meant that I want to access a property on the collection object itself. Real cases of ambiguity can happen, for instance

```
[[1,2,3],['cat', 'elephant']].size == 2
```

but according to the previous notation it should equal `[3, 2]`.

Moreover, if the collect notation was not short enough, there is the `*.` spread-dot operator which is meant to be used exactly in this way:

```
[[1,2,3],['cat', 'elephant']]*.size = [3, 2]
```

> What is the purpose of the ambiguous dot notation? Was it just added to save on character over `*.` or it has legitimate cases of use where `*.` would not work and `collect` would be cumbersome?

Comment: [I too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177651/how-to-extract-a-new-list-from-an-object-field-in-groovy/11177673#comment14671646_11177673) find that the magic behind the `list.prop` syntax is unnecessary and makes things less explicit with no real gain (apart from a single `*`). I cannot tell why it was added, but one can always opt not to use it :)

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a blog post a while ago called ["Groovy Spread Operator Optional For Properties"](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/24/groovy-spread-operator-optional-for-properties-plus-a-peek-into-the-sausage-factory/) that dives into what's going on under the covers in this situation.

The short answer is, it's more syntactic sugar and eventually calls into [DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(Collection, String)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#getAt%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String%29).

There aren't any huge advantages to it, but it could make some DSLs a little easier to write as they can operate correctly whether the object is a collection or a single object.

Comment: Yes, I had already read your post :-) But it does not explain why one should want such behaviour in the first place. I find it extremely confusing, so I wanted to hear some arguments why it was devised

Comment: For instance, can you give some examples of the DSL you mention that would benefit from this syntax?

Comment: Unfortunately the referenced post link is now broken.

Comment: Thanks to the wayback machine we can get to the blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20170224073229/http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/24/groovy-spread-operator-optional-for-properties-plus-a-peek-into-the-sausage-factory/