# Groovy gsp: merge lists

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am trying to merge many lists into a single list in a gsp. For example:

1. Class A has a list of class B instances
2. When i try using the expression: `${a.findAll(some_condition).b}` i am getting a list of lists of instances of B

I would like the expression to return a single list, with all instances of `b` belonging to every `a` that satisfies `some_condition`

Comment: Wait. If a.findAll returns a collection of A objects, how come you call the attribute b directly in the collection? Does that even work? Shouldn't it be like: ${yourList*.b} ??

Comment: @TiagoFarias the `*` is optional. [See Ted's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11366642/6509)

Comment: I did not know that. I guess it makes *. notation useless eh?

Comment: If this is regular groovy objects, then Tim's answer is the best one.  If `A` and `B` are domain objects with a relationship, you can get all of the `B` instances related to some `A` meeting a condition with either criteria using `projections` (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria) or HQL.

Comment: @TiagoFarias the `*.` notation isn't useless in all cases.  For properties, it's optional (ex: `foos.name` or `foos*.name` both return a list of `name` values), but if you want to run a method on everything, it's required to use `*.`, (such as `foos*.toString()`, without the `*.` it'd call `toString` on the list, not each individual value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
${a.findAll(some_condition).b.flatten()}
```

That should get you a single list

```
${a.findAll(some_condition).b.flatten().unique()}
```

Should also remove duplicates